# kong and AWS marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, kong

New to both these technologies.I am trying to do the below steps

1)Install Kong with aws marketplace
I simply clicked on installation on getkong.org
then selected AWS marketplace

2) I am in UK.
So selected region as Ireland
since I have not got any other region to select from.
Then clicked manual launch

I opened ec2 management console
selected free tier
t2.micro

I gave my windows IP and created security groups and instructed but i am getting error
The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=8enaazwzxnn2uypvc4p8u39da for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t2.micro does not appear in the pricing options for this Marketplace offering (it does for other Marketpace images), this leads me to suspect t2.micro isn't supported.

We know from experience that Cassandra may struggle being [run on low memory 2 gig machines](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201603.mbox/%3CCA+VSrLp+q=0NjpFoYEQ-ABfc+EsUfiyVV4Y_b+7stNUb1FAO0A@mail.gmail.com%3E)

I suspect Mashape are trying to prevent you hitting complicated tuning issues (although I cannot see any docs to back this up).

Perhaps start with an M4 Large which is one of the "smallest", cheapest yet memory optimised options for experimentation.

The list of Kong supported ec2 instances for Ireland appear as:[image]

Comment: @ritushreeshukla - glad it helped - feel free to accept the answer and/or up vote to share the love. Ta